# How do I match a CSV-style quoted string in nom?

Tags: csv, rust, nom

A CSV style quoted string, for the purposes of this question, is a string in which:

1. The string starts and ends with exactly one `"`.
2. Two double quotes inside the string are collapsed to one double quote. `"Alo""ha"`→`Alo"ha`.
3. "" on its own is an empty string.
4. Error inputs, such as `"A""" e"`, cannot be parsed. It's an `A"`, followed by junk `e"`.

I've tried several things, none of which have worked fully.

The closest I've gotten, thanks to some help from user pinkieval in #nom on the Mozilla IRC:

```
use std::error as stderror; /* Avoids needing nightly to compile */

named!(csv_style_string<&str, String>, map_res!(
   terminated!(tag!("\""), not!(peek!(char!('"')))),
   csv_string_to_string
));

fn csv_string_to_string(s: &str) -> Result<String, Box<stderror::Error>> {
   Ok(s.to_string().replace("\"\"", "\""))
}
```

This does not catch the end of the string correctly.

I've also attempted to use the `re_match!` macro with `r#""([^"]|"")*""#`, but that always results in an `Err::Incomplete(1)`.

I've determined that the [given CSV example for Nom 1.0](https://github.com/GuillaumeGomez/csv-parser) doesn't work for a quoted CSV string as I'm describing it, but I do know implementations differ.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but why not just use [an existing high-quality CSV parser](https://crates.io/crates/csv)?

Comment: @Shepmaster Two reasons: (1) I want to rewrite the CSV example for Nom to one that's correct to these specifications, thereby helping the community, (2) I have another project where I'm more interested in the PostgreSQL queries than the CSV files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
use nom::types::CompleteStr;

use nom::*;

named!(csv_style_string<CompleteStr, String>,
    delimited!(
        char!('"'),
        map!(
            many0!(
                alt!(
                    // Eat a " delimiter and  the " that follows it
                    tag!("\"\"") => { |_| '"' }

                |    // Normal character
                    none_of!("\"")
                )
            ),
             // Make a string from a vector of chars
            |v| v.iter().collect::<String>()
        ),
        char!('"')
    )
);

fn main() {
    println!(r#""Alo\"ha" = {:?}"#, csv_style_string(CompleteStr(r#""Alo""ha""#)));
    println!(r#""" = {:?}"#, csv_style_string(CompleteStr(r#""""#)));
    println!(r#"bad format: {:?}"#, csv_style_string(CompleteStr(r#""A""" e""#)));
}
```

(I wrote it in full nom, but a solution like yours, based on an external function instead of `map!()` each character, would work too, and may be more efficient.)

The magic here, that would also solve your regexp issue, is to use CompleteStr. This basically tells `nom` that nothing will come after that input (otherwise, `nom` assumes you're doing a streaming parser, so more input may follow).

This is needed because we need to know what to do with a `"` if it is the last character fed to `nom`. Depending on the character that comes after it (another `"`, a normal character, or EOF), we have to take a different decision -- hence the `Incomplete` result, meaning `nom` does not have enough input to make the decision. Telling `nom` that EOF comes next solves this indecision.

Further reading on `Incomplete` on `nom`'s author's blog: http://unhandledexpression.com/general/2018/05/14/nom-4-0-faster-safer-simpler-parsers.html#dealing-with-incomplete-usage

---

You may note that this parser does not actually rejects the invalid input, but parses the beginning and returns the rest. If you use this parser as a subparser in another parser, the latter would then feed the remainder to the next subparser, which would crash as well (because it would expect a comma), causing the overall parser to fail.

If you don't want that, you could make `csv_style_string` match `peek!(alt!(char!(',')|char!('\n")|eof!()))`.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is nom 4's macro style. Here is the new function style.

```
fn csv_style_string(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, String> {
    delimited(
        char('"'),
        map(
            many0(
                alt((
                    // Eat a " delimiter and the " that follows it
                    value('"', tag("\"\"")),

                    // Normal character
                    none_of("\""),
                )),
            ),
            // Make a string from a vector of chars
            |v| v.iter().collect::<String>(),
        ),
        char('"'),
    )(input)
}
```